# Async function inside Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Here is my situation:

```
fetchData(foo).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(result + bar);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve( result + woo);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doSomething(result);
    }, 0)
});
```

Where each setTimeout is a different async operation using the callback pattern.

It is really painfull to wrap each function inside a promise, I feel like the code should look more like this:

```
fetchData(foo).then(result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return result + bar;
    }, 0)
}).then(result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return result + woo;
    }, 0)
}).then(result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doSomething(result);
    }, 0)
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

Am I using Promises right? Do I really have to wrap all existing async function in promises?

EDIT:

Actually I realize my example was not totally reprensentative of my situation, I did not make it clear that the setTimeout in my example is meant to reprensent en async operation. This situation is more representative of my situation:

```
fetchData(foo).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asyncOperation(result, operationResult => {
            resolve(operationResult);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        otherAsyncOperation(result, otherAsyncResult => {
            resolve( otherAsyncResult);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
        doSomething(result);
});
```

Comment: You can use custom event if you don't wanna use promise. This event will be triggered each detect change! ( https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-custom-events/ ) .... But why you don't like using promise?

Comment: There are modules like [`pify`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pify) that can help you promisify existing callback-based async functions. Also, a reasonable number of packages offer _both_ promise and callback support for their async functions (when you don't pass a callback function, they return a promise). But I can't say if this'll apply to your situation.

Comment: ^^ yeah or `bluebird` is very simple, and behaves just like native Promises but more friendly to node style callbacks. [link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.fromcallback.html)

Comment: Why do you apply `setTimeout` inside every `.then`?

Comment: Try `.then(result => new Promise(resolve => asyncOperation(result, resolve, 0)))` No need to be more verbose than necessary. Don't put anything but the smallest code necessary inside promise constructor executor functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I using Promises right? Do I really have to wrap all existing async function in promises?

Yes. Yes.

> I feel like the code should look more like this

No, it shouldn't. It rather should look like this:

```
function promiseOperation(result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        asyncOperation(result, resolve, 0)
    });
}
function otherPromiseOperation(result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        otherAsyncOperation(result, resolve, 0)
    });
}

fetchData(foo).then(promiseOperation).then(otherPromiseOperation).then(doSomething);
```

> It is really painfull to wrap each function inside a promise

Well, don't repeatedly write it out every time. You can abstract this wrapping into a function!

```
function promisify(fn) {
    return value => new Promise(resolve => {
        fn(value, resolve, 0)
    });
}
const promiseOperation = promisify(asyncOperation);
const otherPromiseOperation = promisify(otherAsyncOperation);
fetchData(foo).then(promiseOperation).then(otherPromiseOperation).then(doSomething);
```

Notice that most promise libraries come with a such a promisification function included, so your whole code reduces to these three lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are using promise right. Just a small note on the first snippet of code: you are not returning a promise from the last `then()` callback:

```
...
}).then(result => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doSomething(result);
    }, 0)
});
```

This is correct if you need simply to do an async operation without returning to the caller of `fetchData` the value of the last async operation. If you need to return this value, you need to convert to promise this operation too:

```
fetchData(foo).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(result + bar);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(result + woo);
        }, 0)
    });
}).then(result => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(doSomething(result));
        }, 0)
    });  
});
```

Here I suppose `doSomething` is a **sync** function returning a value.

Said so, if you want to reduce the noise of create the promise to wrap `setTimeout` every time, you can create a utility function `setTimeoutWithPromise`:

```
function setTimeoutWithPromise(operation, millisec) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(operation());
        }, millisec)
    });
}
```

And clean your code:

```
fetchData(foo)
    .then(result => setTimeoutWithPromise(() => result + bar, 0))
    .then(result => setTimeoutWithPromise(() => result + woo, 0))
    .then(result => setTimeoutWithPromise(() => doSomething(result), 0));
```